# Why is numpy.ndarray([0]).all() returning True while numpy.array([0]).all() returning False?

Tags: python, numpy, logic, numpy-ndarray

This seems surprising to me:

```py
import numpy as np
assert np.ndarray([0]).all()
assert not np.array([0]).all()
```

What is going on here?

Comment: ```np.ndarray([0]).all()``` returns empty array where as  ```np.array([0])``` returns array with 0 as element. np.all() checks if there is any False i.e (0)

Comment: `ndarray` is a lower level constructor that we don't usually use.  It's best reserved for cases where you have a preexisting data buffer.  Here's it's more like `np.empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what those two calls produce:

```
>>> np.ndarray([0])
array([], dtype=float64)
```

This is an empty 1-D array, because you specified a single dimension of length `0`.

```
>>> np.array([0])
array([0])
```

This is a 1-D array containing a single element, `0`.

The definition of `all()` isn't just "all elements are `True`", it's also "no elements are `False`", as seen here:

```
>>> np.array([]).all()
True
```

So:

```
np.ndarray([0]).all()
```

is `True` because it's an empty array, while:

```
np.array([0]).all()
```

is `False` because it's an array of one non-`True` element.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the signatures of `ndarray` and `array` were compatible... didn't realize the first arg to `ndarray` was actually a shape.  Thank you!